# How to insert null in a cross join?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a problem here.  I have 2 tables who are linked by the column "id.x"
One table has the weeks of a given month, e.g, for january the table has 5 rows one for each week of the month. The other table represents the effort of an employee in a given week.

I want to join the two tables, but I want in a way that it shows me the efforts of a employee in a given week, so in that case, 5 registries per each employee, even if he hasn't registered effort in some week, in that case we set effort as null.

I'll give you a representation of what I'm looking for and if it's possible.

```
Table 1:
id week month year id.x
1   1    1    2019 7819
2   2    1    2019 7819
3   3    1    2019 7819
4   4    1    2019 7819
5   5    1    2019 7819

Table 2:
employee_id effort id.x week  
   63         100  7819  3
```

Result I want:

```
employee week effort id.x
   63     1    null  7819
   63     2    null  7819
   63     3    100   7819
   63     4    null  7819
   63     5    null  7819
```

Is it possible to reach this result?

I'm currently trying this query:

```
select t2.employee, t1.week from 
table_2 t2
cross join
table_1 tt
order by t2.employee, t1.week;
```

Edit:

And if i want to sum the values of a given week ? E.g:

table 2 now have :

```
employee_id effort id.x week  
       63    60    7819   3
       63    40    7819   3
```

But i want the same answer:

Result I want:

```
  employee week effort id.x
       63     1    null  7819
       63     2    null  7819
       63     3    100   7819
       63     4    null  7819
       63     5    null  7819
```

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a left join, not a cross join. What query did you try and why doesn't it work for you?

Comment: i just edited my currently query.

Comment: an attempt, in sql server though, `select t2.employee, t1.week,
case
when t1.week = t2.week and t1.[id.x] = t2.[id.x] then t2.effort
else null
end
as effort
, t1.[id.x]
from Table_1 t1
left join Table_2 t2 on t1.[id.x] = t2.[id.x]
order by employee, t1.week`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `PARTITION OUTER JOIN`:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 ( id, week, month, year, id_x ) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 1, 2019, 7819 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 1, 2019, 7819 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3, 1, 2019, 7819 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 4, 1, 2019, 7819 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 5, 1, 2019, 7819 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Table2 ( employee_id, effort, id_x, week ) AS
SELECT 63, 100, 7819, 3 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT t2.employee_id,
       t1.week,
       t2.effort,
       t1.id_x
FROM   Table2 t2
       PARTITION BY ( employee_id )
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN table1 t1
       ON (
             t1.week = t2.week
         AND t1.id_x = t2.id_x
       )
```

**Output**:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID | WEEK | EFFORT | ID_X
----------: | ---: | -----: | ---:
         63 |    1 |   null | 7819
         63 |    2 |   null | 7819
         63 |    3 |    100 | 7819
         63 |    4 |   null | 7819
         63 |    5 |   null | 7819
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=42e1951d85e2e1b1285c396f32053c21)*

Comment: Thx you for your answer. But now if i want to sum this values ? imagine that i could have more than one registry per week. How could i sum all then in week 3, for example ?

Comment: use an aggregated query with a sum?

Comment: @Boneist i'm trying "sum(t2.effort)"(in the third line) but it gives me an error.

Comment: @Boneist:
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 24 Column: 8

Comment: You need to add a group by clause. You might want to refresh your understanding of aggregate queries.

Answer (score -1):

You want a result row per employee and week. That is a cross join, which you've already mentioned. Only then outer join your real employee data. Something along the lines of:

```
select *
from employees
cross join weeks
left join employee_efforts using (employee_id, id_x, week);
```

Comment: Not the downvoter, but given the example data there doesn't seem to be a need for a cross join at all.

Comment: Where comes table `weeks` from?

Comment: @Usagi Miyamoto: It's the first table: "One table has the weeks ..."

Comment: Where has the 3rd table come from? The OP's question only has 2 tables.

Comment: You have 3 tables: `employee`, `weeks` and `employee_efforts` while OP has 2: `Table 1` and `Table 2`...

Comment: There are two tables, one with weeks which I took the liberty to call "weeks" and one with employee efforts, which I have called "employee_efforts" accordingly. The employee efforts table has an employee_id which obviously refers to some employee table (whereelse should that ID come from?).

Comment: I am not the downvoter either - the solution you proposed is the "canonical" one, but Oracle introduced *partitioned* outer join many versions ago just for this kind of problem. The better solution is the one posted by MT0 - I believe it will work in Oracle 10.1 and higher.

Comment: @mathguy: I agree. I always forget about the partition clause.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, it gives me the following error:

ORA-01748: only simple column names allowed here
01748. 00000 -  "only simple column names allowed here"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 37 Column: 54

Comment: You get this error when you use a qualifier inappropriately. I am using a `USING` clause on `employee_id`, `id_x`, and `week`, so you cannot use `weeks.week` anymore for instance. Check this. You can use an `ON` clause instead of `USING` in order to keep qualifyable columns.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner it gives me the following error(i think it's because id_x) : 

ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 25 Column: 46

Comment: You are getting this with the `USING` clause or with an `ON` clause? Have you tried both? Do you understand the error messages?